# Youtube API SWFObject Fullscreen button not working

Tags: youtube-api, fullscreen, swfobject

I'm embeding Youtube API player on page via SWFObject. There is a fullscreen button, but when i click it - button goes gray and no fullscreen occures. Testing this on Google Chrome v 37.
Exact embed code:

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" };
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };

swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.youtube.com/v/aowSGxim_O8?            
enablejsapi=1&playerapiid=ytplayer",
"ytapiplayer", "720", "480", "8", null, null, params, atts);
```

Comment: Ah found it: changed url to `http://www.youtube.com/v/aowSGxim_O8?enablejsapi=1&fs=1&playerapiid=ytplayer`, and `params` to `var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always", allowFullScreen: "true" };`